# XCTAssert from another object

Tags: ios, xctest

I'm trying to implement a very simple mock object under the XCTest framework.  I want to be able to call the XCTAssert macros from an object other than the current TestCase object.

I recall being able to do this under the SenTestKit but I can't figure out how to make it work under XCTest.

I feel like the following code sample should fail, but instead it passes.

The only thing I can think of is that (in the example below) MockThing should be a subclass of something other than XCTestCase.  I'm just not sure what that thing should be.

**MyTest.m**

```
@interface MyTest : XCTestCase
@end

@interface MockThing : XCTestCase
- (void) fail;
@end

@implementation MyTest
- (void)testExample
{
    MockThing * mockThing = [[MockThing alloc] init];
    [mockThing fail];
}
@end

@implementation MockThing
- (void) fail
{
    XCTFail(@"This should fail");
}
@end
```

How do I get this to fail properly (without having to use OCUnit).

Comment: you can pass `MyTest` object to `MockThing` but it require to look `XCTFail` to see how to use the object. or just throw exception

Comment: Indeed throwing an exception makes it fail properly.

`NSException * exception = [[NSException alloc] initWithName:@"fail" reason:@"because" userInfo:nil];
 [exception raise];`